# Undesirable vertical stretching of tikz figure inside animateinline on landscape page

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate, pdflscape

Using the following MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape,animate,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (rect) at (0,0) [
        rectangle,
        fill=red,  
        draw=black,
        line width=.5pt,
        rounded corners=.5pt,
        minimum width=1.1cm,
        minimum height=0.8cm,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
    ] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{animateinline}[nomouse,step]{0}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node (rect) at (0,0) [
        rectangle,
        fill=red,  
        draw=black,
        line width=.5pt,
        rounded corners=.5pt,
        minimum width=1.1cm,
        minimum height=0.8cm,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
    ] {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{animateinline}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

You get the following result:

[image: problem]

As you can see by looking at the corners of the second box, the box is squashed vertically inside the `animateinline` environment.

This happens only within the `landscape` environment, which is a requirement for my project. Does anyone have a clue how to resolve this?

Comment: `animateinline` and `\animategraphics` have never worked inside the `landscape` environment of the `[pdf]lscape` packages. I need to investigate this further.

Comment: @AlexG aside of the dimensions problem (that I've found a workaround for, see my answer below), the `animateinline` environment at least seems to work just fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read below, the problem was solved by a package update.

Comment: But note that OCG-(PDF Layer)-based animations are less performing (slower) than Widget-based ones. Shouldn't be an issue though, since you are using the `step` option.

Comment: It's still pretty slow to update though, unfortunately. I'm setting the frame from JS code. Any plans to support landscape in icon mode? I'd love to get in touch about it and see if something can be worked out (professionally perhaps?).

Comment: I will look into this. For the time being, would it be an option for you to put the whole document in landscape mode (`\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}`) ?

Comment: The OCG method is what I will fall back to in the meantime. It's a bit slow but it works. Would love to hear back from you!

Comment: Today I have uploaded new versions of `animate` and `media9`, parts of which `animate` depends upon. It may take a day or two until the new versions will be available in `tlmgr`.  Animations are now correctly inserted on landscape pages with the `(pdf|lua)latex` and `latex`+`dvips` workflows.

Comment: Awesome! I will try it out today. Thanks a lot for the effort! Is there a way for me to "buy you a beer"?

Comment: Confirmed and working!

Comment: And with version `[2017/01/10]` of `pdfbase.sty`, also `xelatex` and `latex`+`dvipdfmx` produce the correct result. (Animation frames and control button faces properly rotated.)